# Is there a purpose for using a static std::set to manage resources of all instances of a class?

Tags: c++, memory-management, std

I inherited some code that I'm in the process of re-factoring, and I came across something where I'm uncertain of the intention. Many (more or less all) of the classes have defaulted to the below pattern, where it appears as though memory management is intended to be handled with a static std::set.

```
class A
{
public:
    A()
    { 
        B_ = new B();
        All_A.insert(this);
    }

    ~A(){ delete B_; }

    static void DestructAll_A()
    {
        for (std::set<A*>::iterator Itr = All_A.begin(); Itr != All_A.end(); ++Itr) 
        {
            A* Obj = *Itr;
            delete Obj;
        }

        All_A.clear();
    };

    static std::set<A*> All_A;

    B* B_;
}
```

My initial thought is that this is bad practice. As far as I can tell there is no discernable advantage with how the classes are being used to have it this way. <s>.In addition, DestructAll_A() does not call A's destructor, so B would never be deleted unless A's destructor is called beforehand, which creates a dependence on order of operations which I find to be confusing (although I suppose that could be done within DestructAll_A())</s>. Lastly, it's unclear to me how it would be differentiated instances of A that were statically vs dynamically constructed (using new).

Am I missing something? What is the general purpose or advantage of using this pattern? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes you're right, my bad. So is this pattern more or less for convenience of not needing to call each instance's destructor?

Comment: This looks like poor man's garbage collection, which may be useful when you deal with batch execution: you run your batch without worrying about freeing memory, and call `DestructAll_A` when you are done. Now the memory is released, and you are ready for the next batch.

Comment: The other issue is whether this is used in a multithreaded program, and the `std::set` is not protected from data races.

Comment: As @Ben Voigt points out in his answer, with this pattern you cannot create an instance of `A` on the stack: you will get an error (or UB) later when calling `DestructAll_A`. see my comment to his answer to have the compiler force this requirement

Comment: @SergeyKalinichenko You mentioned garbage collection, is there any chance of DestructAll_A() getting called implicitly somehow?

Comment: @mSours No, that's not possible, you will need an explicit call somewhere. It could be originating from some destructor, though, so it might not be easy to see.

Comment: @SergeyKalinichenko That was my understanding, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @SergeyKalinichenko I think "poor mans garbage collection" is the answer to my question. While in my specific case I don't think the baggage that comes with it (thread un-safety, dynamic allocation requirement) is a good tradeoff, I would accept that as the answer if you formatted it as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is an attempt at implementing a "poor man's garbage collection". Here is how this could work in a batch processing situation:

- You get a new batch of work, and start the processing
- You allocate the memory as you go, and ignore the need to deallocate it
- Once the batch is over, you call `DestructAll_XYZ` to clean up the mess
- Your system is ready for the next batch

This approach is quick and dirty, so I would definitely recommend cleaning it up at some point. At the very least I would get rid of the static sets, replacing them with something more controllable - say, `BatchMemoryContext` with all the relevant sets in it. This way you would have a tight control of the lifecycle of your objects, and also avoid possible issues with the concurrency.

Answer (score 2):

> `DestructAll_A()` does not call A's destructor

Yes it does.  `Obj` has type `A*`, so `delete Obj` will call the `A::~A()` destructor.  This is undefined behavior for any instance that wasn't allocated using scalar `new A()`.

> Lastly, it's unclear to me how it would be differentiated instances of A that were statically vs dynamically constructed (using new).

It doesn't attempt to differentiate... this class must never be used except with scalar dynamic allocation.

Comment: to force the required "cannot create on the stack", both ctor and the `static set All_A`should be private, and there should be a method `A* CreateA()` that return a `new A()`;

Comment: @GianPaolo: Easier to enforce using private destructor (there's only one) instead of trying to get all constructors including the automatically-generated ones.

Comment: Voigh, thinking about it, you need to delete all the automatic-genereted ctors, if you want all created instaces of A to be deleted by `A::DestructAll_A();` if not this code `A* a = new A(*anotherA); `will leak memory if you don't explicitly `delete a`, wich you could not if you have a private destructor

Comment: @GianPaolo: Or else all the constructors need to register with the set of instances.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment OP ask "is there any chance of DestructAll_A() getting called implicitly somehow?"

Not really in implicit way but almost, the following can do the trick:

```
class A_Cleaner
{
    ~A_Cleaner(){
         A::DestructAll_A();
    }
}

void Main()
{
     A_Cleaner cleaner;

     .... //your program

     // just before reaching the end of main, cleaner dtor is called, so A::DestructAll_A() is called, even in case of exception;
}
```